# c++ - how to initialise reference in other class using 'this' from constructor

Tags: c++, class, vector, reference

I have two classes, Node and Bond; when a new Bond is created I want to add a reference to it to the 'adjBonds' vector in the Node on each side of the Bond (think of it in a chemical sense, with the bonds connecting two atoms)
I can't find a way to get a reference to the current class (Node); do I have to use pointers, and how would I do that?

Also, do I have to clean up std::vectors if they are declared in classes? Do I have to clean up the references in those vectors first, or do references not require memory management?

```
class Node
{
public:
    std::vector<Bond &> m_adjBonds;
    ELEMENT m_element;
    Node(ELEMENT element)
        :m_element(element)
    {
    }

};

class Bond
{
public:
    int m_bondNumber;
    Node &m_end1;
    Node &m_end2;

    Bond(int bondNumber, Node &end1, Node& end2)
        :m_end1(end1), m_end2(end2), m_bondNumber(bondNumber)
    {
        m_end1.m_adjBonds.push_back(this);
    }
};
```

The compiler returns an error on the 'this', saying 'initial value of reference to non-const must be an l-value' but I am not sure what this means.

Comment: Everything has a clearly defined lifetime. Either it's global and always exists, allocated manually with new and exists until it's deleted, or exists within the current stack frame. In other words, it's impossible to know when you should clean up the references/pointers in your vector without more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot have a `vector` of references. Simply change your member to be:

```
std::vector<Bond*> m_adjBonds;
```

The reason for this is that once you assign a reference, you can't *re*assign it. Vectors need to be able to reassign (copy/move) their internal elements around in the case of reallocation, and a reference is neither copyable nor movable.

With C++11, you can make this relationship slightly more explicit via [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Bond>> m_adjBonds;
```

In which case, you'd have to dereference `this` to do the `push_back`:

```
m_end1.m_adjBonds.push_back(*this);
```

---

For the memory cleanup, since you are using `vector` to manage the bonds, that class itself will handle its own memory allocation and deallocation correctly. You do not do any other allocation in your example, so there is no other cleanup that you would have to do.